# Dialogflow CX - accessing language code in flexible webhooks

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I am using flexible webhooks. After an intent has been matched, I want to make a flexible webhook call and I want to pass the detected language code to my webhook controller. I know that the language code is present in the standard webhook requests with the name 'languageCode', but I can't figure out how to get access to this value if I am not using standard webhooks. Clearly, after an intent has been matched, the language is known to Dialogflow CX. How can I pass this language code to my flexible webhooks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference in passing values in **standard webhook** and **flexible webhook**. The `languageCode` can be passed by including it in **Webhook Request** in a **JSON body**.

Sample [webhook request](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/SessionInfo):

```
{
   "detectIntentResponseId": string,
   "languageCode": string,
   "sessionInfo": {
       object  }
}
```

Just follow this creation of webhook resource [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook#create) and apply the [flexible webhook resource settings](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook#flexible).

Comment: I guess my question is, where is the language code stored in Dialogflow? Is it in $session.params? Is it in $intent.params? I can't find it anywhere so I don't have access to it. If I can't reference it, I can't pass it to my flexible webhook. If the webhook doesn't know the agent's language, it can't provide a fulfillment response because it doesn't know in what language it should provide the response. If I use standard webhooks, the language is included in the starndard webhook request object (languageCode). But I prefer to use flexible webhooks. But the language issue is a problem.